# Shiny App Connect dbPool through ODBC or specific driver

Tags: r, database, shiny, odbc

I'm struggling to connect my shiny application to one of the database we use in our company. I've succesfully connected to Azure / Mongo / SQL Server databases but now I've got a SAP SQL Anywhere 17 database to connect to.

Not surprisingly there's no specific connection to that database provided in the R Drivers (https://www.rstudio.com/products/drivers/).

Now I can solve this in two ways I believe, our IT department is convinced that a generic ODBC connection should work, or I have to get the specific SQL Anywhere drivers installed on my shiny app somehow.

For both solutions I can't find much online. If I search for generic ODBC connection the recommendations go to FreeTDS which is in the RODBC package, which then might not work together with Pool (according to what I've read).

Searching how to install specific drivers on a shiny application is also not bringing me much.

Comment: I'd try using library([odbc](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc)).

Comment: Using odbc I don't see a way to use a generic ODBC driver such as FreeTDS, or am I missing something? If I try driver = odbc::odbc() then I get errors.

Comment: Free TDS is mentioned in the "Common DB drivers" section following the above link.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
options(java.parameters="-Xmx8g")
library(RJDBC)
drv <- JDBC("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", "drivers/jdbc/mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar", identifier.quote="`")
processingStart = Sys.time()
conn <- dbConnect(drv,
                  "jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER_NAME;databaseName=DATABASE_NAME",
                  user = "USER_NAME",
                  "PASSWORD"
    )
```